# Change the sorting of every 5 array of number from ascending to descending and vice versa without using php built in function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array number below,

`$arr = [2,5,1,12,-5,4,-1,3,-3,20,8,7,-2,6,9]`

The expected output must be:

`-5,-3,-2,-1,1,20,12,9,8,7,2,3,4,5,6`

The sorting must be change every 5 array of number from ascending to descending and vice versa. So, if the first 5 digits is sorted as ascending, the second 5 digits must be sorted as descending and so on.

But I got:

`-5,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,20`

Below my code:

```
$arr = array(2,5,1,12,-5,4,-1,3,-3,20,8,7,-2,6,9);

function arr_sort($array) {
    // get the size of array
    $countArr = count($array);
    
    for ($i=0; $i<$countArr; $i++) {
        for ($j=$i; $j<$countArr; $j++) {
            if ($array[$i] > $array[$j]) {
                $temporary = $array[$i];
                $array[$i] = $array[$j];
                $array[$j] = $temporary;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // order ascending and descending
    $array = implode(',', $array);
    return $array;
}

print_r(arr_sort($arr));
```

Comment: I still don't understand how you get the output, how does the grouping work?  Do you just take the first array split it into groups and sort or do you sort and then split it into groups and resort?

Comment: I think I would just create two arrays, one sorted up, one sorted down, and then take 5 at a time from each.

Comment: I mean the first sorting is in ascending order, but every multiple of 5 numbers from the sorted array, the sorting method changes from ascending to descending, and changes again every multiple of 5 numbers.

Comment: So you want to sort the input normally array first, and _then_ group these _sorted_ numbers into groups of five? And then reverse the order of every second one of those groups?

Comment: I read it three times, including the comments, and I also don't understand how to get the wanted output.

Comment: I think that OP wants it sorted by: 5 lowest ascending, then 5 highest descending, until there is no more numbers.

Comment: Let me get this straight. I mean, the first 5 number of the output must be ascending (-5,-3,-2,-1,1), and the next 5 number must be descending (20,12,9,8,7), and the next 5 number back to ascending again (2,3,4,5,6 ) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP built-in functions definitely help:

```php
/**
 * @param int[] $numbers
 * @return int[]
 */
function arr_sort(array $numbers): array
{
    // Sort items in ascending order first
    sort($numbers, SORT_NUMERIC);

    $result = [];
    $fetch_lowest = true;

    // Process until the input array is empty
    while (count($numbers) !== 0) {
        if ($fetch_lowest) {
            // Extract the 5 lowest numbers and keep them into ascending order
            $extract = array_splice($numbers, 0, 5);
        } else {
            // Extract the 5 highest numbers and reverse items to descending order
            $extract = array_splice($numbers, -5, 5);
            $extract = array_reverse($extract);
        }

        // Save the extracted items and switch the highest/lowest flag
        $result = array_merge($result, $extract);
        $fetch_lowest = !$fetch_lowest;
    }

    return $result;
}

$input = [2,5,1,12,-5,4,-1,3,-3,20,8,7,-2,6,9];
$sorted = arr_sort($input);

var_dump(implode(',', $sorted));
```

> string(35) "-5,-3,-2,-1,1,20,12,9,8,7,2,3,4,5,6"

Comment: Great. But how can I remove string(35) right there?

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq this is just the var_dump() output, for demonstration purposes. Do whatever you want with the result of the function which is an array sorted as you wanted.

Comment: To remove string(35), I use `print_r`

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq print_r() & var_dump() are just debug functions. You won't use them in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are going for. We chunk the array into groups of 5, then take a grouping one at a time, first from the front, then the back, repeating that pattern. If we take from the back, we then also need to sort it in reverse.

```php
$arr = [2,5,1,12,-5,4,-1,3,-3,20,8,7,-2,6,9];
$a = $arr;
asort($a);

$a = array_chunk($a, 5);

$output = [];
$idx = 0;
while($a){
    if($idx++ % 2){
        $b = array_pop($a);
        arsort($b);
    }else{
        $b = array_shift($a);
    }
    $output = array_merge($output, $b);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/KGgWI